# Javascript displaying image

Tags: javascript

my overall goal is to load an image given user lattitude and longitude. However, my code has an error logic somewhere I assume (document.write("Dog") is never displaying to the screen) so I have to assume something is going wrong. The user is being prompted for a lat and longitude after clicking the button but afterwards nothing is happening. Any Ideas what might be going on? I'm a beginner so i am sure it is something simple.

```
<body>
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x;
            var latittude = prompt("Please enter a lat");
            var longitude = prompt("please enter your longitude");
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location='+ latittude + ',' + longitude + '&heading=235&sensor=false';
            img.height = 200;
            img.width = 300;
            img.alt = alt;
            document.write(img.src);
            document.write("dog");
            document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);
        }
</script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

`img.alt = alt;` but you have not defined a variable named `alt`.

`document.getElementById('body')` but there is no `id` with a value of `'body'`, to reference it use `document.body.appendChild(img);`.

Also unless this is just messing around for practice, take a look at: [Why is `document.write` considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

For future reference if you use the developer tools in your browser (F12) any script errors will be printed out in the *console*.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out based on this! Also, I had absolutely no idea about the developer tools. That is going to make the learning process much easier.